# Kotlin Multiplatform doesn't see files from another directory

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am struggling with writing tests for both iOS and Android native side in Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP). I created a couple of interfaces in one module (it's called `shared`) and created another module, called `sharedTests`, where I created sample test (`FirstTest.kt`). Take a look at pictures below. The problem is, that KMP doesn't see any files from `shared`, why is that? I want to be able to access every file from that directory, how do you tell KMP which directories to look at? Also, I have no idea why are my Test annotations wrong, because I have already added dependencies.

[image]

[image]

```kotlin
import kotlin.test.BeforeTest
import kotlin.test.Test

open class FirstTest(private var concreteApp: IAppWrapper) {

    private lateinit var app: IAppWrapper

    @BeforeTest
    fun setUpTests(){
        app = concreteApp
    }

    @Test
    fun testOne(){
        //testing...
    }

}
```

`shared` Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
}

kotlin {
    android()

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 32
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 32
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.test:monitor:1.5.0")
    implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
}
```

`sharedTests` Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
}

kotlin {
    android()
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "testModule"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 32
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 32
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common:1.7.0")
    implementation("org.testng:testng:6.9.6")
    implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.test:monitor:1.5.0")
    implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")

}
```

Comment: It would be useful to share `build.gradle.kts` from both modules

Comment: Also please avoid screenshots of code, please copy paste the code and error message so it's searchable and people can use it to reproduce your issue: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1540818

Comment: Did you declare test dependencies in your test source sets? Because you seem to have put your test code in your main source set of the `sharedTest` project, so it would be expected it doesn't have access to test annotations from test dependencies. This begs the question, though: do you really want to use main source sets for this test project? Or was it just an oversight?

Comment: @Joffrey I have edited my question, it now contains both Gradle files and FirstTest.kt code

Comment: I don't think the top-level `dependencies` block is valid in Kotlin multiplatform. Dependencies should be declared within the source sets (btw you already did that for `kotlin("test")`, why not for the others? Also, if you want `sharedTests` to see the code from `shared` module, you need to add a dependency on that module, like `implementation(project("shared"))`.

Comment: What do you mean by "top-level dependencies block is invalid in Kotlin Multiplatform"? Should I add these dependencies in the global Gradle file?
Also, when I added kotlin("shared") implementation in sharedModule, Gradle crashed